# Auto assign student role to new registred user in Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I need to assign student role to all users by default who are registering our Moodle site through registration form from frontend. How we can assign student role by default.

Note : If admin is creating new account or uploading bulk users they can assign any roles manually.

Answer (score 0):

The student role is added when a user is enrolled on a course, so is at the course level rather than site level.

It sounds like you want to auto-enrol users on courses? There are a couple of enrolment plugins that will do that:

https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_autoenrol

https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_auto

Comment: Only student can register from registration form. Once they log in we need to redirect to custom page depend on "student" role.

Answer (score 0):

We need to change some settings in admin to achieve this.

In `Administration` > `user' >`Permissions`>`Define roles`

**Edit `student` role :**

change `Role archetype` to `None`.

For `Context types where this role may be assigned` enable `system`.

In `Site administration` > `Plugins` > `Enrolments` > `Self enrolment`

Change `Default role assignment Invalid current value` to `student`

More details here :
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=170956

Comment: In [MDL-26805](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-26805) issue, it said such approach is not recommended.